# Spring Boot 2 Actuator - versions aggregation from multiple microservices

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

We have a Spring Boot 2 REST service app consisting of multiple micro-services. ELB is used for service registration and discovery, e.g. there are services available at

```
http://<dev-env>/api/serviceA/actuator/info
{
  "app" : {
    "name" : "App Name",
    "description" : "App Description"
  },
  "git" : {
    "branch" : "origin/brancha",
    "commit" : {
      "id" : "204f7a0",
      "time" : "2019-07-10T11:09:13Z"
    }
  },
  "build" : {
    "version" : "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT",
    "build" : {
      "version" : "v_0.1.151"
    },
```

```
http://<dev-env>/api/serviceB/actuator/info
....
```

Every service uses SB 2 Actuator.

How can we aggregate this version information from two or more micro-services into single page(kind of dashboard)? Are there any ready solutions?

Answer (score 0):

In your dashboard application just open a http connection and query all the microservices actuator endpoints. There are tons of ways to get started. You should choose one that you are comfortable with.

Comment: The task of aggregating multiple micro-services into single page looks quite common. Are there any ready apps for that?

Comment: What is your dashboard based on? Which technology?

Comment: no dashboard at all yet. Just considering how can we approach the task.

Comment: My approach would be as a first shot to write a little Java or JavaScript tool which just polls the information calling the actuator endpoints. I would then advance this into a dashboard where i could manage the microservices (add/remove/autodiscover). You could even start with a shell script which just loops over the urls and does a `wget`.